# React Forms optimization

Tags: reactjs, optimization, rerender

```
    import React, { useState, useMemo, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";

    
    const Register = () => {
      const [form, setForm] = useState({
        fName: "",
        lName: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        country: "",
      });
      const [errors, setError] = useState({});
      const [contact, setContact] = useState();
    
      const schema = {
        fName: Joi.string().min(10).required().label("First Name"),
        lName: Joi.string().min(10).required().label("Last Name"),
        email: Joi.string().min(10).required().label("Email"),
        password: Joi.string().min(10).required().label("Password"),
        country: Joi.string().required().label("Country"),
      };
    
      const handleContact = useCallback((contact) => {
        setContact(contact);
      }, []);
    
      const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
      };
    
      const handleChange = ({ target: input }) => {
        const { name } = input;
        const errors = validation(input, schema);
        const newFormState = { ...form };
        newFormState[name] = input.value;
        setForm(newFormState);
        setError(errors);
      };
    
      return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          {console.log("Rendered")}
          <Input
            fullWidth={true}
            variant="outlined"
            id="fName"
            name="fName"
            label="First Name"
            value={form.fName}
            onChange={handleChange}
            error={errors ? errors.fName : null}
          />
    
          <Input
            fullWidth={true}
            variant="outlined"
            id="lName"
            name="lName"
            label="Last Name"
            value={form.lName}
            onChange={handleChange}
            error={errors ? errors.lName : null}
          />
    
          <Input
            fullWidth={true}
            variant="outlined"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            label="Email"
            value={form.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
            error={errors ? errors.email : null}
          />
    
          <Input
            fullWidth={true}
            placeholder="Password"
            variant="outlined"
            id="password"
            name="password"
            type="password"
            label="Password"
            value={form.password}
            onChange={handleChange}
            error={errors ? errors.password : null}
          />
    
          <DropDown
            fullWidth={true}
            name="country"
            label="Country"
            options={["Pakistan", "India", "USA"]}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
    
          <PhoneInputField onChange={handleContact} />
          <ButtonComponent
            color="primary"
            disabled={validate(form, schema)}
            variant="contained"
          >
            Register
          </ButtonComponent>
        </form>
      );
    };
    
    export default Register;
```

### How can I stop this rerendering of whole form ? The Input is a custom component wrapped in memo as export default memo(Input).Now, what happens is if I start typing in email input field, the other 2 also gets rerendered. It is because on every update handleChange's references gets updated which causes rerendering the input fields. I have tried wrapping the handleChange in useCallBack but no luck, as the form state is its dependency and every time it changes, the handleChange's reference eventually gets updated.

Comment: Welcome. Please post codeblocks for your example code not image urls.

Comment: post updated with code